# Keep delaying HTTP request until new params are arriving

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Suppose we have a function getIds() which takes an array of some ids
like this:

```
getIds([4, 1, 32]);
```

This function will delay HTTP call for 100ms. But during 100ms if this
same function is called again:

```
getIds([1, 8, 5]);
```

It will reset the 100ms timer and keep merging the passed ids. It will
send HTTP request only if it's not called by anyone for more than 100ms.

I am new to RxJS and here's my attempt to solve this problem but I have
a feeling that there could be better solution for this problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/iFadey/v3v3L0yd/2/

```
function getIds(ids) {
  let observable = getIds._observable,
      subject = getIds._subject;

  if (!observable) {
    subject = getIds._subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
    observable = getIds._observable = subject
      .distinct()
      .reduce((arr, id) => {
        arr.push(id);
        return arr;
      }, [])
      // Some HTTP GET request will go here
      // whose results may get flatMapped here
      .publish()
      .refCount()
      ;
  }

  ids.forEach((id) => {
    console.log(id);
    subject.next(id);
  });

  clearTimeout(getIds._timer);
  getIds._timer = setTimeout(() => {
    getIds._observable = null;
    getIds._subject = null;
    subject.complete();
  }, 100);

  return observable;
}

getIds([1, 2, 3])
.subscribe((ids) => {
  console.log(ids);
});

getIds([3, 4, 5])
.subscribe((ids) => {
  console.log(ids);
});
```

**edit:**
I am looking for an operator which behaves like debounce but without dropping previous values. Instead it must queue them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain to have captured exactly which of the following you are looking for, so I will simply describe both. There are two "time based patterns" that are most often suited for this type of problem in my experience:

- **debounce**

rxmarbles url: http://rxmarbles.com/#debounce ; [github doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/debounce.md)

As it says in its documentation, it

> Emits an item from the source Observable after a particular timespan
>   has passed without the Observable omitting any other items.

- **throttle**

rxmarbles url: none yet ; [github doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md)

> Returns an Observable that emits only the first item emitted by the
>   source Observable during sequential time windows of a specified
>   duration.

Basically, if you would like to wait until the inputs have quieted for a certain period of time before taking action, you want to **debounce**. If you do not want to wait at all, but do not wish to make more than 1 query within a specific amount of time, you will want to **throttle**.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was not looking for these operators. I need an operator which behaves just like debounce but without dropping the previous values. Instead it must queue them. I think my question is bit vague. Let me edit it.